Infinite scrolling leads to IndexOutOfBounds error
I'm encountering an IndexOutOfBoundsException while using a FirestoreRecyclerAdapter in my Android project. The error message indicates that I'm trying to access an index that is out of bounds for my data list.
Error Log:
E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 5
    at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:434)
    at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.getSnapshot(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:70)
    at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.get(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:52)
    at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.java:85)
    at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.java:157)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7254)


Code Relating to the error (Can provide full code if needed):
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VideoViewHolder, position: Int, videoModel: VideoModel) {
    Log.d("VideoListAdapter", "Position: $position, Snapshots Size: ${snapshots.size}")

    // Ensure snapshots has data
    if (snapshots.isEmpty()) return

    // Safely calculate the looped position
    val loopedPosition = position % snapshots.size
    Log.d("VideoListAdapter", "Looped Position: $loopedPosition")

    // Access the model safely with additional bounds checking
    if (loopedPosition >= 0 && loopedPosition < snapshots.size) {
        val loopedModel = snapshots[loopedPosition]
        holder.bindVideo(loopedModel)
    } else {
        Log.e("VideoListAdapter", "Looped position $loopedPosition is out of bounds for snapshots size ${snapshots.size}")
    }
}

Any suggestions would be appreciated
I was trying to implement infinite scrolling in my FirestoreRecyclerAdapter by using Integer.MAX_VALUE in getItemCount() to create an endless loop effect for the video list. I expected it to cycle through the list items indefinitely without issues.
However, I encountered an IndexOutOfBoundsException in the onBindViewHolder method. It seems that using such a large value in getItemCount() caused the adapter to attempt accessing out-of-bounds indices in the snapshots array.
